# google gadget - how to add non-changable preference

Tags: google-gadget, opensocial

Is it possible to store preferences in a google gadget without letting the user to change it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="title"/>
  <UserPref name="pref1" display_name="pref1"/>
  <UserPref name="pref2" display_name="pref2"/>
  <UserPref name="pref3" display_name="pref3"/>
  <Content type="html">
     <![CDATA[ 
       Hello, world!
     ]]>
  </Content> 
</Module>
```

Is it possible to use e.g. "pref2" as a non-changeable preference?

Answer (score 0):

You can save user prefs programmatically. 
for example let say your user prefs declaration looks like this:

```
<UserPref name="enabled"
datatype="hidden"
default_value="true">
</UserPref>
```

then initiate user prefs object like this:

```
var prefs = new gadgets.Prefs();
```

then to set user prefs:

```
prefs.set("enabled", "false");
```

To get user prefs:

```
prefs.get("enabled");
```

In this manner user will not be able to change prefs.
for more details https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/fundamentals#SetPrefs